# Its possible to create a model with objects inside using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I mean, at the moment of creating the model, it is automatically created with one or more objects.

I thought about creating a service with a list of objects and inserting them, then declaring them as a singleton in `program.cs`, but I'm not sure if this is correct or if it will work.

I'm trying to do this with my `Rol.cs` class:

```
public class Rol : Entity
{
    public string Role { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Rol()
    {
    }

    public Rol(string nombre, string descripcion)
    {
        Role = nombre;
        Description = descripcion;
    }
}
```

I want to have the roles of the users already defined.

Could anyone tell me if it's possible or if I'm wasting my time with it?

Comment: Maybe try data seeding in EF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding.

Comment: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)?

Comment: It worked, I used data seeding, thanks!